# regular expressions boost c++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

trying to catch the characters at the start the string and newlines the string is

```
.V/1LBOG\n.F/AV0094/08NOV/SAL/Y\n.E/0134249356001"
```

the regular expression i am using is from the string above i need to catch .V/ and .E/

```
^.[VE]/*
```

But it only seems to ctach .V/ can anyone see why as i thought ^ means newlines aswell as start of strings ? any help will be very gratefull as ive had this problem for a while now. If this is not the correct way as in doing this could you propose a different way.

Comment: you need the "/1LBLOG" and "0134249356001" values rigth?

Comment: no instead of that i need it to check that .V/ and .E/ are present at the start of a new line so its ".V/" not 1BLOG and ".E/" not 0134249356001 hope that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex 101:

`^` means start of string. And you guessed it right. There can only be one start of string.

```
^.[VE]/*
```

means :

Match start of string, followed by any character (other than newline), followed by either a V or a E, followed by 0 to n `/` (greedy).

Probably you want something like this :

```
\.[VE].*?(?:\\n|$)
```

Which means match a dot, followed by V or E and match everything until `\n` or end of string.

Comment if I am wrong.

So `.V/1LBOG\n.F/AV0094/08NOV/SAL/Y\n.E/0134249356001"`

Looks like this ?

```
.V/1LBOG
.F/AV0094/08NOV/SAL/Y
.E/0134249356001"
```

If yes, then you need to change your regex a little bit:

```
\.[VE].*
```

Abusing the fact that `.` does not match newlines by default.

Comment: that is correct but instead of eveything until a \n or end of string it would have to include \n or until the end of string because .E is on a new line ? comment if you did not understand that properly

Comment: yes that is what the string looks like and from that i need to check .V/ and .E/ are present but this regex ^.[VE]/ only catches .V/?

Comment: Yes because as I explained ^ matches the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

if you need .V or .E try `^.(V|E)/*` the or `|` operator is useful for check `^.V/*` or `^.E/*`

Comment: i would need it to check for both but as far as i remember i can just change that operator to the & operator or is it &&

Comment: I recommend you try it yourself with different examples, in any text editor that supports regular expressions. I use text Sublime 2

Answer (score 0):

`.` in regular expressions matches any single character, not a literal `.`. If you want to match a literal period, you need to escape it (`\.`). `*` doesn't match any number of any characters (as most shells would), but instead matches zero or more instances of whatever you put before it. For example, `A*` will match the literal letter `A`, `AAAA` etc., and `.*` will match any string.

`^` means the beginning of a line. `^\.[VE]/` will match `.V/` and `.E/` (but only at the start of the line).

Comment: ok so with the regex search is that possible to also check weather .V/ and .E/ are at the start of the string or new line etc?

Comment: If you use regexp_match() with something like `^\.[VE]/.*$` (`$` is the end of the line), it should match only the lines that start with `.V/` or `.E/`.

Comment: it matches the .V/ but not .E/ only matches if .E/ was the start of the string